# Terminology of $SU(3)_F$

Tags: terminology, group-theory, notation

From a terminological point of view, what is the relatioship between the flavor symmetry group $SU(3)_F$ of strong interaction and the group $SU(3)$ (without subscript $F$) of 3x3 unitary matrices with determinant +1?

Is it possible to say that "the flavor group $SU(3)_F$ is a [representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation) of the [abstract group](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbstractGroup.html) $SU(3)$, defined on the Hilbert space of hadron states or quark states."?

If the previous sentence was correct, one could also state, about the color transformations, that: "$SU(3)_C$ is a different representation of $SU(3)$, acting on the Hilbert space of quark states.".

I have never found sentences of this type in books, so I suspect that there must be something wrong in them. Indeed often representations of the group $SU(3)_F$ (with subscript $F$) are considered, as if it were a "standalone" group. In general I found terminology about groups and representations quite confusing, so please any correction would be appreciared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subscript "$F$" has no mathematical meaning. It's just there to remind the reader what is the physical significance of that group.

For example, a theory may have an $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ flavor group, an $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ gauge group and perhaps maybe even more flavor groups that act on different fields. Whenever a textbook or a paper want to refer to one of these groups in particular they add a subscript in order to save some words.

---

The sentence "*the flavor group [...] quark states.*" that OP states (v1 and 2) is not correct. A given theory can have various particles in different representations of the same flavor group.

---

Gauge groups and flavor groups are fundamentally different. It is not the scope of this answer to explain the difference, but in a few words, gauge groups imply the presence of more degrees of freedom and also imply that the observables must all be singlets under said group.

So if you have a gauge group and a flavor group, they have very different physical implications. If they happen to be the same group mathematically you may need to place a label just to communicate which group you are talking about. It's the *same* mathematical group, but it appears in two different contexts.

Suppose now that you two have groups of the same type, let's say $G_1$ and $G_2$ are both flavor groups. The correct mathematical statement is that the flavor symmetry is $G_1\times G_2$. Now the particles of your theory will transform in some representation of it. But maybe some only transform under the first factor $G_1$ and are neutral under the second $G_2$, and vice-versa for some other particles.

Say, for the sake of argument, that a particle $\phi$ is unchanged under the transformations $(1,g_2) \in G_1\times G_2$. Then you say "*$\phi$ does not transform under $G_2$*".

Now suppose $G_1\cong G_2 \cong \mathrm{SU}(3)$. If you say "*$\phi$ does not transform under $\mathrm{SU}(3)$*" people are going to ask "*which one??*", to which you have to say "*the second one in the product*"... This is cumbersome, so let's just put labels for convenience: $G_1\times G_2 = \mathrm{SU}(3)_A \times \mathrm{SU}(3)_B$ and "*$\phi$ does not transform under $\mathrm{SU}(3)_B$*".

Comment: Is it then correct saying the sentences that I wrote?

Comment: Moreover: If there is no mathematical meaning to attach to subscripts F and C, then color and flavor syimmetries group are exaclty the same from a mathematics poin of view?
So in which way the different physical meaning of the two transformation is mathematically encoded in the formalism?

Comment: @Antonio19932806 see edit

Comment: Excuse me if I insist asking, what do you mean exactly when you write: "A given theory can have various particles in different representations of the same flavor group." ? Do you mean for example that, in strong interaction theory, nucleon states transform with the fundamental repr. of $SU(3)_F$ and pions with the adjoint one? In this case I would say that it is possible to define a (reducible) representation of the group that involves all these particles.

Comment: It makes no sense to put all the particles into the same (reducible) representation. Pions, nucleons, etc.. are different particles, and one of the many ways in which they differ is the representation to which they belong

Comment: For example, they also have different masses and different spins, so it makes no sense to put them in the same multiplet of particles

Comment: I agree, but my point is: let's suppose two flavor symmetry group $SU(3)_A$, $SU(3)_B$ are defined. Take a matrix $U$ in $SU(3)$. This matrix corresponds to two symmetry transofrmations $D_A(U)$ and $D_B(U)$ of particles, where $D_A$ and $D_B$ are two different representations of $SU(3)$, associated with the two flavor groups. The only thing that distinguishes the "physical significance" of the two flavor groups is the particular representation of SU(3) (or the "set" of representations, if more irreducible representations for different particles) that is chosen for them.

Comment: In this sense the sentence "the flavor group $SU(3)_A$ is a representation of the abstract group SU(3), defined on the Hilbert space of hadron states or quark states." should be correct. Don't you agree? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: No because there can be particles with different representations even under $SU(3)_A$. The flavor symmetry is the tensor product $SU(3)_A\times SU(3)_B$ and the transformations are pairs $(g_A,g_B)$.

Comment: The following scenario is possible for instance: particles $p_1,p_2,p_3$ where $p_1$ is singlet under $SU(3)_A$ and fundamental under $SU(3)_B$. $p_2$ is fundamental-singlet and $p_3$ is adjoint-adjoint.

Comment: Because *representation* has a precise meaning in mathematics. Perhaps you mean to say an "instance" of the group. Like **my** "$<$insert brand$>$ phone" is an instance of an "$<$insert brand$>$ phone". Meaning that $SU(3)_A$ and $SU(3)_B$ are both $SU(3)$'s, but two different ones. If you are familiar with python they are `==` but not `is`. I don't know how else to explain it.